# RAM stress test

Tags: hardware, upgrade, memory

I'm spec-ing a new MacBook Pro and want to know how much memory my workload requires. I'm doing my development work on a 2011 iMac with 16GB of RAM and want to know if I need that much memory for my new MBP since RAM is not upgradable.

I created a 8GB RAM disk and a random 7GB file to see the memory pressure on my Mac:

```
diskutil erasevolume HFS+ 'RAM Disk' `hdiutil attach -nomount ram://16777216`
dd if=/dev/urandom of=temp_7gb bs=1 count=0 seek=7g
```

To my surprise, it had almost no impact on the memory pressure chart in Activity Monitor! Am I doing this right? How can I simulate that my current Mac only has 8GB of memory?

Comment: I would be cautious with buying a computer with "only 8 GB" of RAM in 2019. While it's certainly sufficient for most things today, you have to think about 2-5 years from now. With the prominence of heavy JavaScript on sites, and everyone writing shit-tier electron apps, RAM is going to be a valuable resource to have.

Comment: @klanomath it's to create a 7GB file with random bytes. I pilfered it from some forum so it may not do what I want

Comment: @MikeHenderson: That command skips over the first 7G of the file (`seek=7g`) and then writes 0 blocks (`count=0`) of size 1 octet (`size=1`). In other words: it will write nothing at all. All it does is create a *sparse file* with a 7G hole at the beginning and no content otherwise. The whole size of the file will be negligible (basically just the metadata for describing the "hole").

Comment: Do you want this new MBP to last you a few years? Is your workload and software going to remain exactly consistent for that time? Always over-estimate

Comment: Just FYI: [MacPerformanceGuide.com](https://macperformanceguide.com) : His professional photographer's demands and technical competence informs his technically Insightful, detailed review of and commentary on Mac hardware and OS.  I visit this site frequently.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Open Terminal, enter:

```
sudo nvram boot-args="maxmem=8192"
```

and reboot. This will limit the RAM to 8 GiB. Now start using your Mac with the usual workload.

To reenable the full 16 GiB-RAM simply enter `sudo nvram -d boot-args` and reboot again.

---

Your dd-command won't work as intended, because the number of blocks written is 0 (count=0) and the block size would be 1 Byte (bs=1). As far as I can tell only a "file" with the size of 7 GiB is created in the file system catalog but no data is written to the file itself at all. If the count would be 1 (count=1), 1 Byte of random data would be appended to the file temp_7gb (seek=7g).

The destination (of=temp_7gb) is dubious. It creates a file in the working directory. You either have to cd to a file system on the RAM disk (e.g. `cd /Volumes/RAM-Disk/`) first to create the file there or write directly to the RAM-disk device (of=/dev/devX).

**dd** is a tool which rather measures disk I/O than CPU load/speed or memory usage/pressure.

With a clever combination of dd operands you still can use it to simulate CPU load/memory usage.

1. `if=/dev/urandom or if=/dev/zero` are related with the CPU speed
2. `of=/dev/null` the disk won't be involved.
3. `bs=x` determines the memory usage (x is almost proportional to memory usage)
4. `count=y` gives you time to test things

Examples:

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=1 count=1000
```

mainly measures the system-call overhead (including any Spectre / Meltdown mitigations your kernel uses, which make system calls slower than they used to be).  Cryptographically-strong random numbers also takes significant computation, but 1 system call per byte will dominate that. The memory footprint is low (on my system about 400 kB)

```
dd if=/dev/urandom of=/dev/null bs=1g count=10
```

mainly measures the CPU speed because it has to compute a lot of random data. The memory footprint is high (on my system about 1 GB).  `bs=1m` would be about the same but use much less memory.

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=1g count=10
```

mainly measures the memory bandwidth (here ~7 GB/s) for the kernel's `/dev/zero` driver doing a `memset` in kernel space into `dd`'s buffer.  The memory footprint ~= buffer size, which is much larger than any caches.  (Some systems with Iris Pro graphics will have 128MiB or 256MiB of eDRAM; testing with bs=128m vs. bs=512m should show that difference.)

The kernel's `/dev/null` driver probably discards the data without even reading it so you're just measuring memory write bandwidth, not alternating write + read.  (And system-call overhead should be negligible with only a read+write per 1GiB stored.)

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/null bs=32k count=100000
```

mainly measures the CPU Cache-write bandwidth (here ~13 GB/s) and system-call overhead. The CPU has not much to compute (zeros!); the memory footprint is low (on my system about 470 kB).

L1d cache size is 32kiB.  You'd think `bs=24k` would be faster (because it fits easily in L1d instead of having more evictions because dd's buffer isn't the only thing in L1d), but increased system-call overhead per kB copied might make it worse.

L2 cache is 256kiB, L3 is 3 to 8 MiB.  `bs=224k` should see pretty good bandwidth.  You can run `dd` on each core in parallel and bandwidth will scale because L2 caches are per-core private, unlike shared L3 and DRAM.  (On many-core Xeon systems, it takes multiple cores to saturate the available DRAM bandwidth, but on a desktop/laptop one core can come pretty close.)

Comment: The OP's 2011 iMac has a CPU with an integrated memory controller, like all x86 CPUs since then.  DRAM bandwidth is not necessarily the same as bandwidth to the southbridge, and reading from `/dev/zero`  in 1GB chunks is mostly just making the kernel do a big memset.  (And discard the result).  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_QuickPath_Interconnect has a diagram that shows QPI is for system <-> DRAM or CPU, not for CPU <-> DRAM.

Comment: And BTW, `bs=32k` bottlenecks on system-call overhead as much as the minimal cost of a 32kB memset.  With Spectre + Meltdown mitigation, system calls overhead is significantly higher.  13GB/s is [laughably low](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/329789/how-can-cache-be-that-fast) for cache write B/W on one core.  Even though L1d size = 32kiB, you'd probably see `dd` throughput go down if you shrink it to 24k so you're more likely to get all L1d hits, no evictions.  Or go up if you grow it to `bs=224k` (just below L2 size of 256kB).  These are Intel's cache sizes since Nehalem.

Comment: @PeterCordes :-) While writing the dd-addendum, I knew that some assesments may be **bold**. **Before** appending it to the answer I indeed visited the linked wikipedia article because I didn't really knew, how modern CPUs are linked to the main memory (I knew: no FSB+NB anymore). Most important - I had it on the tip of my tongue, but I needed someone else to mention it - are the words *system-call overhead*. I'll try to improve the answer - feel free to do the same (with more expertice than I have).

Comment: Sure, added a suggested edit.  I have gold badges in [performance], [x86-64], and [cpu-architecture] over on Stack Overflow so you can probably take my word for it :)

Comment: @PeterCordes Considering the weighting between the boot-args answer (4%) and the dd-digression (96%) (the result of a sloppy forum article: *Mike Henderson's comment:  ... I pilfered it from some forum so it may not do what I want*), we have to modify the question now ;-)

Comment: xD.  Yeah that's a bit of a side-track.  And really has nothing to do with stealing memory from the OS.  Maybe should just be removed, if there's a similar answer on unix.SE or something.  The OP was just using `dd` to create a known-size file in a ramdisk, not hoping that dd itself would tie up memory.    (uncompressable data from urandom defeats zswap or whatever, if MacOS does that; I don't know MacOS well at all)  Oh, except they were trying to make a sparse file.  /facepalm.  (Apparently MacOS supports storing sparse files on top of HFS+, even though HFS+ itself doesn't)

Comment: @PeterCordes I ought to find the forum article and add the dd-part as a comment there. The proposed dd command (`dd if=/dev/urandom of=temp_7gb bs=1 count=0 seek=7g`) is useless. Nothing is written (count=0) and the proper destination (either cd to RAM-disk or a valid of (of=/dev*X*/)) is missing.

Comment: Yeah, exactly.  It needs `count=1` to make a sparse file so it's not even doing the probably-useless thing.  It needs no seeking at all to actually zero-fill, like `bs=1m count=$((7*1024))`